# libVLC creates two audio streams

Tags: c++, qt5, playback, libvlc

I'm using libVLC to play a video file. If I use my code in as standalone video player, I am having no issues. The video plays very well. I can pause and play the video as I like.

When I use the same code, **without** modifications, in a plugin, and then play the **same file**, something unique happens: VLC creates two audio streams for the same video file. Now if I pause the video using `libvlc_media_player_pause(...)`, it pauses the video and one audio stream. The other audio stream continues playing.

Any suggestions as to why this could be happening?

The application itself is written in Qt5. I have tested this issue with both audio and video files.

LibVLC version is 3.0.0

[Header file](https://pastebin.com/zpanZbmt) and [Source file](https://pastebin.com/XyxZHfyc) are pastebin links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake I did was in the code for plugin. Two instances of NBAVPlayer were created in the plugin code leading to two audio streams, one visible video stream and one hidden video stream. I have fixed the issue with the plugin, and now everything works properly.